# Using ruby gem/command from python

Tags: python, shell, command, subprocess, haml

I've installed the Ruby gem 'haml' on my mac, which I can use to compile haml files into html files using the following command at the terminal:

```
haml 'path/to/haml/file.haml' 'desired/html/path/file.html'
```

This command simply creates an html file at the second path, and gives no output in the terminal. So for example, this command:

```
haml "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Sites/ICSP/sugar.haml" "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Sites/ICSP/sugar.html"
```

Creates a sugar.html file at the given path. Now I'm trying to use this functionality from a python script. When I type this into IDLE's interactive python shell:

```
>>>import subprocess
>>>subprocess.Popen('haml "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Sites/ICSP/sugar.haml"        "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Sites/ICSP/sugar.html"', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x159d6f0>
```

I get output suggesting that the process has been run, however, there is no file outputted. Why is this happening? I even put in the Shell argument, but no interactive shell shows up. Also, I read somewhere that the default shell used is not bash, which is what the Mac terminal uses, so I put that in too for good measure.

Following icktoofay's advice, I ran check_call. Here is the traceback I received:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/neil/Desktop/subprocesstest.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       p = subprocess.check_call(x, shell=True)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
>   line 504, in check_call
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) CalledProcessError: Command 'haml
>   "/Volumes/Macintosh
>   HD/Users/neil/Sites/ICSP/sugar.haml"
>   "/Volumes/Macintosh
>   HD/Users/neil/Sites/ICSP/sugar.html"'
>   returned non-zero exit status 127

According to the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), while searching for a command to be executed,

> If the name is neither a shell
>   function nor a builtin, and contains
>   no slashes, Bash searches each element
>   of $PATH for a directory containing an
>   executable file by that name. ... If
>   that function is not defined, the
>   shell prints an error message and
>   returns an exit status of 127.

However, I thought it was indeed finding the haml command after adding the shell and executable arguments, because before that, it was giving a 'file or directory not found error', which indicates that the function is not executable directly but rather in a shell only.

Now how do I make python find this haml command? Or would I have to use some ugly workaround like an applescript which then invokes the haml command.

Comment: Have you tried using [`subprocess.check_call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) instead of directly using [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)?

Comment: Sorry the question seems so long now, but I've tried to provide as much information as possible to make debugging easier.

Comment: You've probably tried something like this, but does this work (with the paths changed obviously)? `subprocess.check_call(['/path/to/haml', '/your/file.haml', '/your/file.html'])`

Comment: Turns out putting the full path to haml in the original call works perfectly. Now how do I make this device independent, ie, how can I make python find haml? Or should I ask users of the script to put haml into their system path or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using, `shell=True`, so I would have expected things to just work. Checked it locally here with Python 2.7.1 and haml 3.1.1 and I had no problems executing it. There are also some python implementations you might be interested in, [PyHAML](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyHAML), [HamlPy](https://github.com/jessemiller/HamlPy), [djaml](https://github.com/chartjes/djaml) or [django-haml](https://github.com/fitoria/django-haml).

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['haml', 'hello.haml', 'hello.html'], shell=True)

% cat hello.html
<strong class='code' id='message'>Hello, World!</strong>
```

Comment: I did actually use the `shell=True` argument. I'll try using the full path to haml, but since I'm guessing this would vary from computer to computer, it would be difficult to turn this into a distributable script. Also, I did look up the python implementations earlier, but it seems like they're not just a python bridge to call the haml compiler, they actually handle the compiling themselves, sometimes resulting in a different output than the official haml gem's output. I'd rather not risk using a python implementation that might fall behind in syntax support in the future.

Comment: @Neil ah I see that now. Should just work then. Very odd. Maybe a bug with haml? I just tested it and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

[shlex.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) is your friend, when you want to build `args` list suitable for `Popen` and its ilk.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import shlex
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('haml "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Sites/ICSP/sugar.haml" "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Sites/ICSP/sugar.html"'))
>>> p.wait()
0
```